# how to install pymysql sing raspbian os in raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, pymysql

how to install pymysql using raspbian os in raspberry pi 3.. because when I run the coding in the terminal it show "no module name pymysql"

Comment: ARM platform is different , need rebuild a module before installing(**make!**).

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and use

`$ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL`

Comment: share the full traceback